# Putting a url in an email that opens an application on iPhone or iPad

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, email

I know what code is needed to cause my iOS app to open a link in Safari. But I am looking at how I might accomplish something more in the reverse direction.

I can send email from my app. I would like to include a link in the email, that, when clicked on within the email on my iPhone or iPad, will open my app and perform an action based on the property values passed in the link. (The link would refer to a record in the database of my app, so the app can provide a view content based on that record.)

Another example I have seen is the special purpose URL used in the manifest file that loads ad hoc distributions over the air.

I see something like this when places and dates are automatically converted to links that open the map or calendar applications.

Does anyone have an idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a [custom URL scheme](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html).

Comment: Thanks. This is going to be a great feature for my app! The link you gave explains it very well.